# How do I correctly use a bool with an if statement?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, boolean

I have this method called "DoStuff()" and what it does is that it checks if the checkboxes are checked and if they are then does something.

```
private void DoStuff()
{
  if(Checkbox1.isChecked == true)
    {
      DoSomething();
    }

  if(Checkbox2.isChecked == true)
    {
      DoSomething();
    }

  if(Checkbox3.isChecked == true)
    {
      DoSomething();
    }

}
```

How do I correctly set a bool so I don't have to do "== true" for every if statement?

Comment: But then it wont know if its a bool or not?

Comment: if i remove the == true I get this.. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) "

Comment: How would setting a bool help? Instead of `== true`, you'd have to still write `== MyBool`.

Comment: bool? is not bool, it can be null as well.

Comment: Any question that has this number of the answers should be upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

As checkboxes can be tri-state (checked, unchecked & undetermined) then you'll have to leave the `== true` in place as `Checkbox.IsChecked` is a nullable boolean which can't be tested simply like a standard boolean.

Even if the checkbox is bi-state and can't be set into it's indeterminate state by the user `IsChecked` remains a nullable boolean as it can be set to `null` programmatically.

In this case there is absolutely no harm in leave the code as has you have it. Anything you do to try to remove the `== true` will more than likely make the code less readable, less maintainable and potentially less stable. You can, for example, just do this:

```
if ((bool)Checkbox1.IsChecked)
{
}
```

But this will raise a NullReferenceException if the checkbox is ever in the indeterminate state, and so is not good practice at all.

[MSDN page on the `IsChecked` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JonnyKhanas Is that error with the code in your question or after you removed the `== true`? I can't see that happening in the former case, but is expected in the latter.

Comment: It happend after I removed `== true`

Comment: @JonnyKhanas - which is perfectly correct. The `IsChecked` property is a nullable boolean (`bool?`) and you can't do an implicit conversion to a boolean (`bool`). You have to leave the `== true` in the code. There is no other clean, safe way of writing this.

Comment: Then why is everyone telling me to remove `==true` because when I remove it, thats when I get the error.

Comment: @JonnyKhanas they were wrong to tell you to remove the `== true`. If yo notice those comments and answers have now been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

bool? is a nullable type and can be 'true', 'false', or 'null'.

If you know the value won't be null then you can do:

```
if(Checkbox1.IsChecked.Value)
```

or if you didn't know whether it was null:

```
if(Checkbox1.IsChecked ?? false)
```

but there is nothing wrong with keeping `== true` either...

Answer (score 0):

Anything you place in the brackets after the if must be a boolean value, the code will not compile otherwise. Essentially it only understands if(false) and if(true)

IsChecked is a nullable bool, it can be true, false or null. The ==True is needed so that you are left with a "predicate" that can be resolved as either true or false.

if ischecked is null then .IsChecked == true will be false, if IsChecked is false the .IsChecked == true will also be false. Only when .IsChecked == true, only then will it return true and move into the if block

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but reading your comments it sounds like you are dealing with a nullable boolean.  In which case it can be null, true or false.  Nullable objects have a property .HasValue that should be checked prior to accessing.  If HasValue is true, then it is not an null object.

Your code would look like this:

```
if(checkbox.IsChecked.HasValue == true && checkbox.IsChecked.Value == true)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

A slightly shorter version:

```
if(checkbox.IsChecked.HasValue && checkbox.IsChecked.Value)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

The bool is "hidden" behind a nullable object, so you access the bool using `Value`.  First, you need to check `HasValue` and if that is true, access the bool via `Value`.  If `HasValue` is false then `Value` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method as below

```
public static class BoolExtensions
    {
        public static bool GetBoolOrDefault(this bool? val, bool defaultval)
        {
            return val.HasValue ? val.Value : defaultval;
        }
    }
```

And use like this way

```
    private void DoStuff()
    {
      if(Checkbox1.isChecked.GetBoolOrDefault(false))
        {
          DoSomething();
        }

      if(Checkbox2.isChecked.GetBoolOrDefault(false))
        {
          DoSomething();
        }

      if(Checkbox3.isChecked.GetBoolOrDefault(false))
        {
          DoSomething();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply use `??` ?

Comment: ohh yes @EricLippert that's also a good way to deal with bool thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[CheckBox.IsChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `Nullable<bool>` property

if statement requires a straight bool

by `== true` you are getting an implicit cast

option

```
Debug.WriteLine(cb1.IsChecked.ToString());
//Debug.WriteLine(((bool)cb1.IsChecked).ToString());  // this fails on null
if (cb1.IsChecked ?? false)
    Debug.WriteLine("cb1.IsChecked ?? false");
if (cb1.IsChecked ?? true)
    Debug.WriteLine("cb1.IsChecked ?? true");
if (cb1.IsChecked == true)
    Debug.WriteLine("cb1.IsChecked == true");
```

what you are getting with == true is cb1.IsChecked ?? false

Answer (score -1):

You can do :

```
if (Checkbox1.Checked)
```